# Para que serve a propriedade DataTransfer?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou aprendendo *drag and drop* em *JavaScript* e não estou compreendendo bem para que é que serve a propriedade `DataTransfer`, por exemplo a sintaxe dela seria algo como:

```
event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
```

Ela seria para transferir dados do arrasto, mas transferir quais dados e para onde? no exemplo acima eu estou setando um dado com o `setData`, mas esse dado vai ir para onde para uma variável? Já a parte `text/plain` são palavra-chaves que eu devo usar que são definidas na própria linguagem do *JavaScript* ou eu posso criar as minhas próprias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataTransfer` é usado para guardar os dados que estão sendo arrastados durante uma operação de Drag e Drop, podendo guardar um ou mais tipos de dados.

Cada objeto `DataTransfer` contém uma propriedade de itens, que é uma lista de objetos `DataTransferItem`. Um objeto `DataTransferItem` representa um único item de arrasto,cada um com uma propriedade tipo e uma propriedade tipo para o tipo mimetype do item de dados. O objeto `DataTransferItem` também tem métodos para obter os dados do item de arrasto `.stringfile`.
Por exemplo, você pode arrastar dados da área de trabalho para o navegador.

Comment: Valeu, colega! :)